# Change Context Menu Icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change the context menu icon during runtime? There seems to be no option in the [update method](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-update).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the `setIcon` method of the BrowserAction. Within the ContextMenu you can only specify the items shown in the menu, not configure the icon itself.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon

Comment: The `setIcon` method only changes the icon of the toolbar button. The icon in the context menu is still the default one.

Comment: Then I'm a bit confused about what your context menu is. Could you maybe verify?

Comment: I create a context menu entry with following code: `chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Do something", "contexts":["all"], "onclick": OnContextMenuCreate});` Then I want to change the title and the icon of the entry. Until now I only can change the title with this code: `chrome.contextMenus.update(1, {"title": "Do nothing", "onclick": OnContextMenuCreate} );` Changing the icon seems not to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's been possible for some time, include a following line to the root of your `manifest.json` file:

`"icons": {"16": "icon.png"}`

The context menu icon size is 16px; you can also define other sizes used in different use cases.

Comment: While this answer explains where the icon comes from in the first place, it does not answer the question; OP asks about dynamically updating the icon from code.