# Can the icon of a context menu item of a Firefox web extension be changed on the fly?

Tags: firefox, icons, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-webextensions

I developed a web extension for Firefox with `manifest.json` containing:

```json
    "icons": {
        "16": "Open In New.svg"
    },
```

and the `background.js` containing:

```js
browser.menus.create( {
  id: 'myContextMenuItem',
  title: browser.i18n.getMessage('contextMenuItemLabel'),
  contexts: ['link']
} )
```

The icon declared in `manifest.json` is the extension's icon and is also used in front of the context menu item label. Can the latter be changed programmatically on the fly?

I found [Change Context Menu Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9499620/1744774) but that has no answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can update with [menus.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/update). For example:

```
browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "do-not-click-me") {
    var updating = browser.contextMenus.update(info.menuItemId, {
      icons: {16: 'something.svg'}
    });
    updating.then(onUpdated, onError);
  }
});
```

Comment: "[_`icons` can only be changed on menu commands, not on the top-level context menu._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/update#Parameters)"

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica That was a snippet of the code. Post updated although not tested.